# Spring Webflux redirect all 404 pages to index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I am unable to find an answer to the following question:
How can I redirect all unhandled(no controller) url's to index.html ?
I have found the following guide
[webflux redirect root path to index](https://medium.com/@davidecerbo/serving-static-resources-with-spring-webflux-and-kotlin-ad831cbd26eb)

but that does not help redirect other url that are unmapped like: http://localhost:8080/blabla , this will result in a 404 page

If I add the following bean, it will override all existing controllers and no api will be accessible

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> indexRouter(@Value("classpath:/public/index.html") final Resource indexHtml) {
        return route(GET("/**"), request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(indexHtml));
    }
```

Is there known solution for this issue?
I can use nginx to redirect all unrecognized path to root path, but that is ugly, and I really don't want to add another layer just for redirecting.

Thanks :)

Comment: if you are using router functions, all routerfunctions will be read from the top and down, which means it's pretty much like a switch case, you can place a "default" case at the bottom, that will redirect the client to a specific endpoint. So "/" (slash) will return your index, then a get function that matches on "/**" will return a redirect to a hard slash.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I'd post that as an answer - I was just typing something similar :-)

Comment: haha okey @MichaelBerry

Comment: @ThomasAndolf  and what if you put them in different classes:
https://lankydan.dev/2018/03/21/creating-multiple-routerfunctions-in-spring-webflux
should you create dependency in the beans? to make sure it is load last?

Comment: that is one way, you can also use `@Order` annotation i think, there are several ways, but im not really shure! try it out! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `RouterFunctions`, all router functions will be read from the top and down, which means it's pretty much like a switch case.

This means that you can place a "default" case at the bottom, that will redirect the client to a specific endpoint.

So in your example `/` (slash) will return your `index.html`, then a `GET` function that matches on `/**` will return a redirect to a hard slash `/`.

Comment: Can I extend this solution to redirect _all_ but _only_ 404 pages to index.html? In other words, let requests to existing static resources serve them, only redirect to index.html if there's no controller and no static resource?

Comment: Well if i understand correctly, you should in theory first list all your hard links, and then lastly have a default catch all case `/**`

Comment: I've done this but it doesn't work. The `/**` is at the end of the collection of router functions but it's the one that's invoked every time even if there are exact matches above it.