# How to handle 404 error when using Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

Application I'm working serving static files of a frontend application inside the spring cloud gateway. At the moment any route other than the predefined once are ended up being 404 as expected.

```java
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> htmlRemoteAppointmentRouter(
      @Value("classpath:/static/index.html")
      Resource html) {
    return route(GET("/"), request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html))
        .andRoute(GET("/home/{*path}"), request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html))
        .andRoute(GET("/user/{*path}"), request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).bodyValue(html));
}
```

How ever, what I'm expecting is to handle the 404 error and serve the index.html for all the failing GET requests.

I tried to add the `/error` mapping. However on client, it still shows the `Whitelabel Error Page` for 404.

```java
@Controller
public class ErrorHandler implements ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String something() {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: you should check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254535/spring-cloud-gateway-global-exception-handling-and-custom-error-response

Comment: I asked the same question(only not in the SCG), but it shouldn't matter to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321371/spring-webflux-redirect-all-404-pages-to-index-html

The router beans are loaded via the order in the class from top to bottom (or via the use of @Order annotation), you can simply add a redirect to all unmapped(/**) to the UI at the button of the class, or even better at a new router file with Order lowestPriority

Answer (score 1):

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}")
public class ErrorHandler implements ErrorController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public String errorHtml() {
        return "custom error controller";
    }
}
```

The request mappings are basically copied from the source code of BasicErrorController.
See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/BasicErrorController.java

The `@ResponseBody` annotation is needed because the method is returning a string. The other two `@RequestMapping` annotations are directly copied from the source code.

Comment: I only tested in Spring Boot. I don't know if there is something specific in Spring Cloud Gateway that would cause issues.

Comment: If you simply want to route absolutely everything to index.html, why not just declare the router function to match `all()` routes.
`return route(all(), request -> ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).body(html));`

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Cloud Gateway you should extend AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler. As you're using RouterFunction i guessed webflux involved there. The next example is extracted from spring boot (v2.7.3) docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#web.reactive.webflux.error-handling):

```
@Component
public class MyErrorWebExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {
    
    public MyErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, Resources resources, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes, resources, applicationContext);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(this::acceptsXml, this::handleErrorAsXml);
    }
    
    private boolean acceptsXml(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.headers().accept().contains(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    }
    
    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleErrorAsXml(ServerRequest request) {
        BodyBuilder builder = ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        // ... additional builder calls
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```